# Calling .py file within function

Tags: python, function

I want to run a py file within function.

I have a .py file that name is "style.py" and that file has some arguments such as "image", "gpu", "output" etc.

I run this .py file in terminal like:
`!python style.py -gpu 0 -image xyz.png -output abc.png`

I want to run this file within function like:

```
def run_image_py():
   !python style.py -gpu 0 -image xyz.png -output abc.png
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is e. g. "os.system" to run a subprocess (and more advanced functions).

Comment: Is it your py file? Can you modify it? Why not just import it and call a function from it?

Comment: Since everybody seems to suggest [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) I'd like to cite the documentation of that function: "The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os` module to run commands like you would in terminal.

So for your problem you could do this:

```
import os

def run_image_py():
   os.system("!python style.py - gpu 0 -image xyz.png -output abc.png")
```

And the function should return the process return value!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `os` module

```
import os

def run_image_py():
    os.system('!python style.py -gpu 0 -image xyz.png -output abc.png')
```